Legal status of copyright licenses
From what I understand, a copyright is granted by a governing body - thus the copyright owner presumably must choose from a set of offered copyright filings. Alternatively, they are assigned one based on the type of work.
Copyright licenses, on the other hand, are inter-party agreements between copyright owners and those wishing to use the work. The potential for the more informal status of licenses could be represented in, for example, 'promissory estoppel' during litigation.
However, it seems possible to me that a governing body could only recognize a limited set of licenses as well. How strictly are licenses related to the copyrights' they release, in various states/jurisdictions? Can licenses be arbitrarily formulated with respect to the copyrights they intend to apply to? Are all legally recognized licenses in some way registered with a governing body, or are 'unregistered' custom licenses common (related question)?
To expand, presumably I can't write to a copyright office just saying 'give me a copyright for x' - they offer me a set of forms/copyrights to choose from, and I have to fill them out appropriately to get a particular copyright conforming to some standard (ofc assuming I've shown proof of ownership). On the other hand, licensing can happen informally (even in ways that can be brought to court): as simple as 'you can use this for now'. Rephrasing my question: are there legal mappings between copyrights and the licenses they can be released under? Can we can mix and match licenses with copyrights arbitrarily (within reason)?
For a concrete example, does CC-0 need to be 'registered' by each government as a valid license, or is its statement sufficient? They seem to imply limited recognition in their legal code:

CC0 is a universal instrument that is not adapted to the laws of any particular legal jurisdiction, similar to many open source software licenses. And while no tool, not even CC0, can guarantee a complete relinquishment of all copyright and database rights in every jurisdiction, we believe it provides the best and most complete alternative for contributing a work to the public domain given the many complex and diverse copyright and database systems around the world.


Why do you think there are different kinds of copyright?

@phoog for instance, the categories of works of authorship from the 1976 Copyright Act have varying stipulations

Well the closest thing to your idea of copyright being "granted" by a government body is the idea in US law of copyright registration--formerly required but not since the US implemented the Berne convention. Requirements for registration differ depending on the type of work, of course--a sound recording of a performance of a choreographic work is likely to be of little use. It is for similar reasons that the rights being protected vary somewhat from one category to another. Any dispute about what's protected is settled in court after an alleged infringement, not by the copyright office.

Copyright arises automatically upon creation of an original work. This does not require any government decision maker or administrative act. It happens due to the effect of statutory law.
Copyright grants to the copyright owner a set of exclusive rights — things that only they can do with the work. The precise list of rights depends on the jurisdiction, but generally, this bundle includes the right to copy, the right to distribute copies, the right to perform, the right to communicate the work to the public, the right to produce a derivative work, etc. There is a high degree of uniformity between jurisdictions because of the Berne Convention.
A copyright owner can give anyone else the permission to do any of those things that otherwise, only the copyright owner could do. And, subject to the ordinary constraints of contract law, the copyright owner can condition these permissions on obligations that the licencee agrees to (although assignment of the right is more closely controlled in some jurisdictions — requiring it to be in writing, or limiting it's availability — this answer is about licensing, not assignment).
There is no role for the government to "register" these agreements.

Ah, so presumably a license really only has bearing in a jurisdiction inasmuch as it addresses the corresponding list of rights granted by the jurisdiction's statutory law?

The U.S. does require assignments of copyrights to be in writing so there is some regulation of agreements between parties regarding copyrights.

Also, there are some jurisdictions where assignment of rights is not permitted except through inheritance

@DaleM Germany separates the economic rights (freely sellable) and the author's rights (only inheritable)

@shea well yes. A license that purports to grant or withhold a right that the licensor does not possess is meaningless.  I would add that licenses are not registered with the government because the primary mechanism for enforcing copyright is through private court actions (lawsuits) filed by the person whose copyright has been (allegedly) infringed. The parties to the suit will give the court a copy of the license agreement at that point (or perhaps argue about what the license agreement actually was or even whether one existed at all).  This seems inefficient, but since most licenses ...

... are never the subject of a disagreement, it's probably more efficient to do it this way than to evaluate (or even just register and archive) all the millions of such agreements that must come into existence every year. (On top of this, a license doesn't necessarily need to be granted in writing; if I tell you that you can make a sound recording of my concert so you can listen to it at home, that's a license.)

"There is no role for the government to "register" these agreements." - A partial exception to this applies in the case of compulsory licenses.  Under some circumstances, a party can submit a notice of intention to obtain a compulsory license.
